# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (python2)

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

I'm using python2 (`Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)|`) to plot some things.

However, when I declare a matplotlib figure I get the following error:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pylab as plt
>>> fig = plt.figure(1)
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40807) with this library (version 0x40805)
Aborted
```

I haven't found this error before! what could be the problem? I appreciate your help.